# Display characters around regex match

Tags: ruby, regex

Is it possible to display the characters around a regex match? I have the string below, and I want to substitute every occurrence of `"change"` while displaying the 3-5 characters before the match.

```
string = "val=change anotherval=change stringhere:change: foo=bar foofoo=barbar"
```

What I have so far

```
while line.match(/change/)
  printf "\n\n Substitute the FIRST change below:\n"
  printf "#{line}\n"

  printf "\n\tSubstitute => "
  substitution = gets.chomp

  line = line.sub(/change/, "#{substitution}")
end
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get down and dirty Perl style:

```
before_chars = $`[-3, 3]
```

This is the last three characters just before your pattern match.

Comment: I programmed in Perl for years 'n years, and think that "down and dirty" and "Perl" are synonymous and somewhat redundant. :-)

Comment: It's so dirty that I can't find a way to write *dollarsign-backtick* in code style. Few people are likely to know what that even is, but it works.

Comment: I feel dirty now, because I know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You would likely use `gsub!` with block given in the following manner:

```
line = "val=change anotherval=change stringhere:change: foo=bar foofoo=barbar"

# line.gsub!(/(?<where>.{0,3})change/) {
line.gsub!(/(?<where>\S+)change/) {

  printf "\n\n Substitute the change around #{Regexp.last_match[:where]} => \n"
  substitution = gets.chomp

  "#{Regexp.last_match[:where]}#{substitution}"
}

puts line
```

Yielding:

```
 Substitute the change around val= => 
111
 Substitute the change around anotherval= => 
222
 Substitute the change around stringhere: => 
333

val=111 anotherval=222 stringhere:333: foo=bar foofoo=barbar
```

`gsub!` will substitute the matches in place, while more suitable pattern `\S+` instead of commented out `.{0,3}` will give you an ability to print out the human-readable hint.

Comment: Is this ruby version specific I am on 1.8.7? I'm getting this error: ./test.rb:69: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<where>\S+)change/

Comment: In ruby 1.8.7 you are to use index of regexp match instead of named matches: `line.gsub!(/(\S+)change/)` and then `#{Regexp.last_match[1]}`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative: Use $1 Match Variable

tadman's answer uses the special prematch variable (**$`**). Ruby will also store a capture group in a numbered variable, which is probably just as magical but possibly more intuitive. For example:

```
string = "val=change anotherval=change stringhere:change: foo=bar foofoo=barbar"
string.sub(/(.{3})?change/, "\\1#{substitution}")
$1
# => "al="
```

No matter what method you use, though, make sure you explicitly check your match variables for nils in the event that your last attempted match was unsuccessful.